# WPF server application

Tags: c#, wpf, sockets, client-server

I have a WPF server and client applications.
When I launch the server, it begins listening to incoming messages. However, the application cannot be touched or closed, it's "stuck" in listening. I must add that it does what it should do, in the matter of processing the message etc. But I just can't interact with the form.
Is it related to asynchronous server socket? I'm not sure what to look for...

Here is my server code:

```
    private void startServer()
    {
        sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        sck.Bind(new IPEndPoint(0, serverPort));
        sck.Listen(100);

        while (true)
        {
            Socket accepted = sck.Accept();

            Buffer = new byte[accepted.SendBufferSize];
            int bytesRead = accepted.Receive(Buffer);

            byte[] formatted = new byte[bytesRead];

            for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++)
            {
                formatted[i] = Buffer[i];
            }
            string command = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(formatted);
            string[] splittedCommand = command.Split(' ');

            jobsHistory.Items.Add(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(formatted));
            jobsHistory.Refresh();

            Process processToRun = new Process();
            processToRun.StartInfo.FileName = splittedCommand[0];
            processToRun.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(splittedCommand[0]);
            processToRun.StartInfo.Arguments = "";
            for (int i = 1; i < splittedCommand.Length; i++)
            {
                processToRun.StartInfo.Arguments += " " + splittedCommand[i];
            }

            processToRun.Start();
            accepted.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If this works on the UI thread then you are tying it up in the loop. It doesn't have a chance to process any UI events. In addition to that `Socket.Receive` is a blocking call.

There are numerous articles on the BackgroundWorker` class both on this site and Google. I suggest you look into those.

Answer (score 1):

Just perform listening in a separate thread, like this -

```
    private void startServer()
    {
        sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        sck.Bind(new IPEndPoint(0, 8080));

        new Thread(() => StartListening(sck)).Start();
    }

    void StartListening(Socket socket)
    {
        socket.Listen(100);

        Accept(socket);
    }

    void Accept(Socket socket)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Socket accepted = socket.Accept();

            Buffer = new byte[accepted.SendBufferSize];
            int bytesRead = accepted.Receive(Buffer);

            byte[] formatted = new byte[bytesRead];

            for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++)
            {
                formatted[i] = Buffer[i];
            }
            string command = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(formatted);
            string[] splittedCommand = command.Split(' ');

            jobsHistory.Items.Add(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(formatted));
            jobsHistory.Refresh();

            Process processToRun = new Process();
            processToRun.StartInfo.FileName = splittedCommand[0];
            processToRun.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(splittedCommand[0]);
            processToRun.StartInfo.Arguments = "";
            for (int i = 1; i < splittedCommand.Length; i++)
            {
                processToRun.StartInfo.Arguments += " " + splittedCommand[i];
            }

            processToRun.Start();
            accepted.Close();
        }

        // If you want to start listening again
        socket.Close();
        startServer();
    }
```

Comment: First, thanks for the reply. It works now. But, If I connect, then disconnect, then reconnect again, An exception is thrown, saying: "Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted".

Comment: @Idanis that may be because you are performing the action too quickly and the socket has not actually been released yet.

Comment: try closing the `socket` and then call `startServer` again... see my update for `Accept` method...

Comment: I modified my code. Just wanted to show the big picture. I have a "Listen" button which changes to "Disconnect" when the socket is listening and vice versa. As you can see, I added the changes, but now I can't disconnect nor reconnect...What am I missing here? Thanks...

Comment: i think you should open a new question with your connecting/disconnecting issue, there will be good chances of getting answers there. Meanwhile if this answer solved your original problem, please mark it as answer so that it would be helpful for other ppl searching for the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `BeginAccept` to accept connections in the background without blocking the UI thread. When a client is accepted, call `BeginAccept` again - this creates a "loop". You can remove your `while` loop then.

The `startServer` method could look like this:

```
private void startServer()
{
    sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    sck.Bind(new IPEndPoint(0, serverPort));
    sck.Listen(100);

    sck.BeginAccept(Accepted, sck);
}
```

Then, in the `Accepted` method, do this:

```
private void Accepted(IAsyncResult result)
{
    Socket sck = result.AsyncState as Socket;
    Socket client = sck.EndAccept(result);

    sck.BeginAccept(Accepted, sck);
}


        Socket accepted = sck.Accept();
```